# Python error: not enough values to unpack and main.py not specified

Tags: python

So I was doing some python exercise and been stuck on one which teaches parameters, unpacking and variables so the code goes like this

```
from sys import argv
main.py, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", main.py)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

but the error I get running this directly on compiler is

```
    main.py, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Now if I run the code with terminal using command `python3 main.py first second third` as the book says I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    main.py, first, second, third = argv
    NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

help would be appreciate

Comment: first check `len(argv)`. And don't use names with dot - `main.py` - because dot has special meaning in Python - `module.function`. Use ie. `main_py` or `main`

Answer (score 0):

well, when you do:

```
main.py, first, second, third = argv
```

you expect to have always four argouments passed to oour file when started, but the `Value Error` is telling to you that only one has been passed.

Then the second error is raised because you use `main.py` to define a variable, but you can't use `.` in variable names, so simply turn your code in:

```
main, first, second, third = argv
```

then it should be adviceble to use some `try: ... except:` statement to handle errors in that part to avoid the brogram crashing when you pass the wrong number of arguments.

if you have a program that requires command line arguments like in that case you have always to start it with the arguments.

to avoid the first error you have to start the file like you do after in the question ,but will work only if you solve the second error.

```
import sys

try:
    main, first, second, third = sys.argv
except ValueError:
    first = input("first: ")
    second = input("second: ")
    third= input("third: ")

#main is the name of the file ,if you eant you can get it using __file__
```

in the above way you could avoid any error and if for any reason you start the file without passing any arguments, it will ask you them via shell.

Comment: Can you tell me the possible ways to get past the first error?

Comment: i've edited the question, if you founded it useful please consider to upvote it, or if you want sign it as the correct one